# possible to test ASP.NET website for mobile device on LAN

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, mobile, emulation

We have a test server on the LAN on which we test web pages in ASP.NET before deploying them to the production webserver.  Desktop PCs connected to the LAN are the workstations, running various browsers.

But is it possible to test with *actual* mobile devices if the test server is not on the internet? We've tried three emulators, and they are showing wildly different results for the same devices.

We're using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: sure just connect them to the same network.

Comment: How do the mobile devices connect to the LAN, Daniel?

Comment: It all depends. Is wifi available?

Comment: There's no WiFi, all hard-wired.

Comment: this sounds like it belongs on [sf].

Comment: How to test whether one's code and CSS are working properly on a target device is not considered part of mobile app (hybrid) programming? I'm asking if there are other ways of attaching these devices to a network, perhaps via an external website that serves as a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a WiFi router, connect it to the test network. Mobile devices connect to the WiFi network and can then access the sites.

Probably should password protect the WiFi.

Comment: I gather the mobile device would refer to the LAN webserver by its IP address.

Comment: @Tim That might be the easiest to get up and running. But you can also configure your mobile device to talk to a DNS server on your network. But since it's a test environment presumably being used by people comfortable with entering an IP address (have them bookmark it, or add it to their mobile device's home screen) the IP address approach is probably simplest.